# Smooth text align animation within box?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a box that expands with content inside
Is there a way i can make it so the h1 tag smoothly slides over to the left of the box when hover?
and is there a way to make it on click instead of hover?

````
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>

  </head>
  <body>
<div class="coolbutton">
  <h1>HEADING</h1>
</div>
  </body>
<style>
.coolbutton{
  width: 250px;
  height:55px;
  background-color: black;
  border:solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-decoration: underline 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  transition: width 1s, height 1s, border-radius 1s, text-decoration 1s;
}
.coolbutton:hover{
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-decoration: underline 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
.coolbutton h1{
  color:white;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
.coolbutton:hover h1{
  text-align:left;
}
</style>
</html>```
````

Comment: You need to look for CSS properties that are animatable in order to get smoothness. e.g. left and transform to center the header and to move it left. To do it with click you can using e.g. an invisible input checkbox or alternatively use JavaScript so as not to have to change the HTML. Which is preferable?

Comment: probably javascript